# Why are soft photons considered undetectable?

Tags: photons, experimental-physics

Wikipedia says that [soft photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_photon) are undetectable. Yet, single photon counters exist for visible photons with relatively high quantum efficiency. So why can’t one set up an experiment to detect visible photons ( 2 - 3 eV) emitted by beta decay or a high energy particle decay with > 1MeV of energy? If the definition of soft photons is simply those with low energy relative to the underlying process, then any visible photon emitted in a high energy nuclear or particle process should qualify, right?

Comment: So lets say you have a detector for photons of energy $2-3$ev, what about those of $0.1$ ev? or $0.01$ev? The detector will always have some lower bound on the energy it can detect, and any photon with energy below that bound will be a soft undetectable photon.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the 'soft' energy scale is such that it includes only the photons, whose energy can not be detected. This is typically less than any other energy scale of any experiment involving 'hard' particles. It doesn't matter how low your remaining energies are. The softness of a photon is directly related to your ability to measure it..